# PARENTGROUPVAL to calculate Amount Percentage in Reports

Tags: reporting

I am currently having a Currency field on Opportunities (say 'My_Revenue__c'). Now, I am trying to calculate the sum of 'My_Revenue__c' for all Closed Won Opportunities divided by the sum of All Closed Opportunities (Closed Won + Closed Lost).

Basically, I want the percentage of the amount. To that, I tried using the PARENTGROUPVAL and made the below formula:

```
PARENTGROUPVAL(Opportunity.My_Revenue__c:SUM,GRAND_SUMMARY)/Opportunity.My_Revenue__c:SUM
```

For the above formula, I grouped on the basis of Stage. Also, am only including the Closed Opportunities in this report. But, it is giving me the wrong percentage.

Am I on the right path? I am a bit confused whether to put this on 'All Summary Levels' or 'Grand Total Only' or 'Specific Groups'.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I used the below formula:

```
(Opportunity.My_Revenue__c:SUM)/PARENTGROUPVAL(Opportunity.My_Revenue__c:SUM,GRAND_SUMMARY)
```

Also, I applied this to the 'Specified Groups' Stage. And BOOM, I got the exact results.

Hope this helps.